# Couldn't find application in API

Tags: mulesoft

I've created one sample application in Anypoint Studio and tried deploying it in the cloudhub. Status shown there is "successfully deployed", but when I try opening the URL generated there, it is throwing "502 bad gateway - we couldn't find any cloudhub application listening to this API" error. Please help me with this. Thankyou!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you show what you have tried already.

Comment: did you find any information from `error log` ?

Comment: Exported my application as mule application so that it will create one jar file with my application name in local system. And in cloudhub, deploying the same jar file , it;s status is "deployed", but when I try opening the link/URL which is automatically generated there.. it's throwing that "502 bad gate way " error.

Answer (score 0):

The application is probably listening to a port not supported by CloudHub load balancer. It should listen to 8081 for HTTP and 8082 for HTTPS.

See https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-networking-guide#load-balancing for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the 502 error message. Aled is correct. I had changed the listening port because I had another server running on 8081.

`<http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8080" />`

Changing this value back to 8081 and redeploying to the Anypoint platform resolved the issue.